# Android AIR application developed in Flash CS6 did not run smoothly on mobile phone

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have developed AIR application for Android in Flash CS6. 
But the problem is, the application doesn't run smoothly on mobile phone.
I can't find the solution to my problem. Is it because of too many scenes or too many key frames in a scene?

Thank you so much for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

at first, take a look at [**this**](http://blog.flexwiz.net/top-10-performance-killers-in-your-air-application/)

when you find issues with only phones, it means that device is not enough strong to execute and render your app as fast as you want:

i know following points strongly change your performance in phone devices

1. using complex vectors, and trying to update them each frame (scale
   is most harmful case)
2. high definition screen resolution of device (*in this case you must avoid full-screen if necessary*)
3. using CPU as render target, it must be changed to GPU (not even
   direct)
4. a 24-30 fps would be best because you have more chance to play and
   **create** everything with same speed as runtime fps
5. [memory management and garbage collection](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-garbage-collection-in-as3--active-4412)
6. using bitmap objects instead vector graphics, you can keep storing
   vectors in your app for advantage of reducing disk size, but its
   possible to rasterizing them in runtime and letting CPU breathing
   easily

Comment: Changing it into GPU cause some of the interface to look different and using 24 fps still won't make my app run smooth. So I decided to use less effects on the images and it run a little bit smoother than before. But the no 5 solution is very helpful ! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Daniella my suggestion is **Adobe Scout**, helps you detecting any thing which generates lag in your app